# Force cleanup of temporary variables

Tags: c++, memory, temporary-objects

(Please excuse me if this question is a duplicate, I'm a beginner and had no idea what terms to search for in order to find an answer!)

I am trying to write a linear algebra library with some very rudimentary memory management for c++ - essentially using shared_ptrs; once the ptr count reaches 0, it returns the memory to the manager.
The arrays I am dealing with are quite large in size, and memory comes at a premium, so I'm trying to force the code to trigger cleanup of redundant memory variables as soon as possible.

Consider:

a,b,c,d,e are NOT temporary variables, ~5GB each.

z = a+b+c+d+e

or alternatively

z = add(a,add(b,add(c,add(d,e)))) - this is how I've actually coded it so far, no operator overload.

I'm finding that the temporary variables (one for each operation) only go out of scope once the equality operation completes, and therefore the shared_ptr still thinks the memory is in use. As a result, the cleanup of the scratch space occurs all at once, where in theory the single chunk of memory holding 'd+e' could be thrown away once 'c+d+e' is stored, and so on.

Obviously this is causing huge bloat in the memory usage, as instead of 5GB in scratch space being used, it takes up 20GB.

To work around it to date, I have had to do the following

z = d+e

z = c+z

z = b+z

z = a+z

This allows the previous temp variable to go out of scope at each new line, but it causes some pretty nasty bloat in several parts of my code.

Is there any way to force the code to return the temp memory back to the manager earlier than end-of-line? I'm thinking there might be something I can do to the shared pointer, or passing by reference instead of value, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

To clarify, what I'm looking for:

allocate memory for (d+e), perform calculation

allocate memory for (c+d+e), perform calculation, release (d+e)

allocate memory for (b+c+d+e), perform calculation, release (c+d+e)

allocate memory for (a+b+c+d+e), perform calculation, release (b+c+d+e)

assign (a+b+c+d+e) pointer to z

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    int fooid;
    Foo(int fi) {
        fooid = fi;
        std::cout << "Creating array " << fooid << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "Cleanup array " << fooid << std::endl;
    }
};

Foo mult(const Foo &a, const Foo &b)
{
    //std::cout << "Constructing new foo" << std::endl;
    Foo out(a.fooid*b.fooid);
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    Foo twos(2); //placeholders for huge non-temporary arrays
    Foo threes(3);
    Foo fives(5);
    Foo sevens(7);
    Foo elevens(11);
    std::cout <<"Method 1" << std::endl;
    Foo vx = mult(mult(mult(mult(twos,threes), fives),sevens),elevens);
    //std::cout << vx.fooid << std::endl;
    //system("pause");

    std::cout << std::endl <<"Method 2" << std::endl;
    //Alternative, over 3 lines, forces destructors earlier than above, more scratch space for the later operations
    //Note array 30 is deleted before array 210 is constructed, unlike Method 1
    Foo vx1 = mult(twos, threes);
    vx1 = mult(vx1, fives);
    vx1 = mult(vx1, sevens);
    vx1 = mult(vx1, elevens);

    std::cout << std::endl <<"End" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output as below:

```
Creating array 2
Creating array 3
Creating array 5
Creating array 7
Creating array 11
Method 1
Creating array 6
Creating array 30
Creating array 210
Creating array 2310
Cleanup array 210
Cleanup array 30
Cleanup array 6

Method 2
Creating array 6
Creating array 30
Cleanup array 30
Creating array 210
Cleanup array 210
Creating array 2310
Cleanup array 2310

End
Cleanup array 2310
Cleanup array 2310
Cleanup array 11
Cleanup array 7
Cleanup array 5
Cleanup array 3
Cleanup array 2
```

The key difference between the methods above is that Method 2 has the capacity to free old temp variables before performing the next step of the calculation, whereas the first method holds on to all of its memory before the calculation is entirely finished. I'm hoping to find a way where I can have the outcome of method 2 while coding more along the lines of method 1.

Sorry for the frequent edits. Wanted to get it right.

Comment: Variables go out of scope (and are destroyed) when the scope they are in ends - your "workaround" would not achieve that, unless `d` actually constructs an anonymous temporary (in other words this code is too pseudo to demonstrate what you are actually having issues with)

Comment: Sorry. Consider a,b,c,d,e are NOT temporary, what I mean is that (d+e), (c+d+e), (b+c+d+e), (a+b+c+d+e) are all allocated in memory until the assignment operator, and then they are all released at once..

Comment: Please create an actual [mcve], to me the question is too abstract to tell when you expect variables to go out of scope and be destroyed

Comment: common matrix libraries (like eigen an opencv) create "expression" types when adding or multiplying matrices that aren't evaluated until they are assigned to a matrix. perhaps you could use a similar method.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, my first post. I'll get back to you with a more concrete example

Comment: [When is the destructor of the temporary called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29375747/86967)

Comment: You could overload the `add` method to accept rvalue references. That would let you reuse the temporaries.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. I've tidied up the sample a bit to make it a bit clearer (hopefully). I'll look into expression  types / rvalues :)

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer, as of C++11 (and at least partially implemented by good compilers prior to that), is to accept your arguments by *value*.  This seems counterintuitive, since it sounds like more copies, but in practice the ownership of existing data is transferred into the function by move constructors (and/or compiler magic).

You then update the “copy” you receive *in place* and return it, where it may very well get its resources transferred into *another* function call to be reused/updated again.  At the end of the full expression, several destructors will run (C++17 *might* run them when each function returns because of “mandatory [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)”), but most will be for moved-from objects whose resources have already been reused and/or released.

Of course, each function of equal-sized arguments needs at most *one* of them in which to store its result; since most operators are left-associative, the obvious choice for the by-value parameter is the first.  You could define variants of, say, subtraction with the second operand passed by value to catch cases like `z=a-(b*c)`.

Comment: Thanks! To make it work, do I need to explicitly define A& operator=(A&& other) and A& operator=(const A& other) as well as both types of constructor?

Comment: To hopefully clarify : With a pass-by-value approach, how does the code accommodate an lvalue being passed? Do I need to implement a deep copy constructor or assignment operator for lvalues to be used in conjunction with this approach?

Comment: @SRB121: If an lvalue is passed, you do make a copy of it—but you needed to allocate one more unit of space for the return value anyway, so if you reuse it that’s no problem.  Yes, you do need a proper (“deep”) copy constructor to handle that, and move assignment would be helpful as well.  If your class has handle semantics, you might be able to detect a reference count of 1 and reuse resources that way.  (You would still want move construction to make those reference counts be 1.)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to write a linear algebra library with some very
>   rudimentary memory management for c++ - essentially using shared_ptrs;
>   once the ptr count reaches 0, it returns the memory to the manager.
>
> ...
>
> a,b,c,d,e are NOT temporary variables, ~5GB each.

If you are creating `a linear algebra library` to practice your programing skills then good.
But you've written about `variables, ~5GB each`! This means you are solving some serious problem. If I were you I would use ready library `gmp` for example. Reason is simple. This library was crated and optimized by many smart people for a thousands of hours. This way you will remove one problem from "equation".

This very large size of matrix suggest another thing you should read about is [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). It is possible that this will make your data more compact and will speed up calculations.

When you use library then cleaning memory of already used variable will be simple (calling some function called something like `clean`). So your question won't be a problem.

I'm suspecting that your question is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), consider providing more information which are less general